# Logic app managed identity api connections not selected/authenticated after a terraform deployment

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

If I deploy a logic app workflow that has connections that use the logic apps user assigned managed identity in terraform, the api connections show as invalid...

[image: https://academy.useinsider.com/docs/upsert-user-data-api]

I have to manually go in and select them and then save the logic app.

[image]

I'm using ARM templates via terraform. An example api connection looks like this following...

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_sql_name": {
            "defaultValue": "sql",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "uksouth",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_sql_name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/sql')]"
                },
                "parameterValueSet": {
                    "name": "oauthMI",
                    "values": {}
                },
                "displayName": "[parameters('connections_sql_name')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The connection is then referenced in the workflow here...

```json
"sql": {
    "connectionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('connections_sql_externalid'))]",
    "connectionName": "sql",
    "connectionProperties": {
        "authentication": {
            "identity": "[parameters('userAssignedIdentity')]",
            "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
        }
    },
    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/sql')]"
}
```

And then in an action like below...

```json
"Get_order_details_from_Narvar_on_dates": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": {
            "query": "SELECT\tSH.ORDER_NUMBER, \n\t\tSH.ORDER_DATE, \n\t\tSH.DELIVERY_AMOUNT,\n\t\tSL.SKU, \n\t\tP.PRODUCT_NAME, \n\t\tSL.UNIT_PRICE, \n\t\tSL.LINE_AMOUNT, \n\t\tSL.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, \n\t\tSL.QTY_ORDERED,\n\t\tP.COLOUR, \n\t\tP.SIZE, \n\t\tP.ITEM_URL, \n\t\tP.ITEM_IMAGE \nFROM F_C_SALES_HEADER SH\nINNER JOIN F_C_SALES_LINE SL on SH.SKEY_SALES_HEADER = SL.SKEY_SALES_HEADER\nINNER JOIN D_C_PRODUCT P on SL.SKEY_PRODUCT = P.SKEY_PRODUCT\nWHERE SH.EMAIL_ADDRESS = '@{body('Parse_data_stream_message')?['attrs']?['email']}' \nAND SH.ORDER_DATE >= DATEADD(year, -@{parameters('backfill_years')}, GETDATE()) \nAND CONVERT(date, SH.ORDER_DATE) in (@{concat('''', join(variables('Backfill Order Dates'), ''','''), '''')})"
        },
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('narvar_server_name')))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('narvar_database_name')))}/query/sql"
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Check_for_any_orders_to_backfill": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
```

Everything appears to be hooked up correctly so why do I have to re-select/re-authenticate these connections manually?

Comment: Is this [blog](https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html) works for you? @Konzy262